# Bytecode not visible for deployed contract

Tags: solidity, bytecode

Below is the contract that is used to deploy other contracts using only bytecode.

I tried to deploy the contract using deployBytecode function, the contract gets deployed but only 0x is showing as bytecode. Pls, anyone help to solve this issue.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.5;

contract DeployBytecode {
    
    // Create contract from bytecode
    function deployBytecode(bytes memory bytecode) public returns (address) {
        address retval;
        assembly{
            mstore(0x0, bytecode)
            retval := create(0,0xa0, calldatasize)
        }
        return retval;
   }
}
```

[image: Deployed contract bytecode]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: it might be helpful to be more specific on your question. Is this question about the `DeployBytecode` contract or about the contract that should be deployed and what `bytecode` are you using?

Looking at your `deployBytecode` function (especially the `assembly` block) there are some things that don't look correct:

1. `mstore` is used to put 32-bytes into memory. The first parameter is the target position in memory and the second parameter is the value. In your case you store the pointer to the start of `bytecode` in memory position `0`.
2. `create` takes 3 parameters: `value`, `location of deployment code` and `length of deployment code`. In your case you fix the location of your deployment code to `0xa0`, which is not always correct. Also you use `calldatasize` as the length of the deployment code, but you are not actually using calldata, so this is also not correct.

I would propose the following changes:

1. remove the `mstore`
2. Change the `create` to have the following parameters: `0` (for the value), `add(bytecode, 32)` (for the data location), `mload(bytecode)` (for the data length).

Lets take a detailed look at the data location and data length parameter:

To understand these values it is important to understand how a `bytes` is stored in Solidity. The variable value of `bytes` is the location of the data in memory. In memory the bytes is stored by having first the length of the bytes and then the data, this results in the following schema: `<32-bytes length><data>` at the location where `bytecode` points to.

Now if we want to use the data with `create` we first point to the start of the raw data, which is after the length. Therefore we add 32 (the space required for the length) to the location stored in the `bytecode` variable. This is the first parameter. For the second parameter we read the length from memory using `mload`. As the length is the first 32 bytes at the location of `bytecode` we can read the length by calling `mload(bytecode)`.

A full example that is used in production can be found here: https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/1.3.0-libs.0/contracts/libraries/CreateCall.sol#L22-L29

More information about assembly/yul can be found in the [Solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.7.0/yul.html#evm-dialect)

Comment: I've updated the DeployBytecode contract with the changes you've suggested, but still I end up with the new deployed contract - bytecode being 0x.

I'm trying to deploy new contract with the same exact bytecode as this contract - https://bscscan.com/address/0x2bf75fd2fab5fc635a4c6073864c708dfc8396fc#code

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, contract gets deployed, but no bytecode ? Sorry for not adding more info in the Question. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Your deployment bytecode is different from the runtime bytecode. The deployment bytecode is the input of the creation transaction: https://bscscan.com/tx/0x40199a77396f223ec3b9558e3bdf01832743433bd486c1758f901aba545270ba

Comment: I'm having trouble deploying this contract - https://bscscan.com/tx/0xa23b43e6d670087dd65ca7f7cb9b90e96b9c3ffabfe283e92ebefb074f5ad1ed , with other contracts I'm having success. Pls shed some light on this. Thanks